# UPDATE: iam_policy_document: Error: InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Policy Error: null status code: 400, request id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, terraform0.12+

so I am trying to migrate a non-modular Terraform setup to be made up of modules. I have run into this error. I know it is not a terraform specific error, but  Terraform is what I'm using.

The whole structure of all the modules needed to make this happen include these:

```
%ls

caller_identity     event_rule  event_target    iam_policy_document sns_topic_policy
```

in the caller_dentity:

```
ls
main.tf     output.tf   variable.tf
```

in event_rules:

```
main.tf     output.tf   variable.tf
```

in event_target:

```
main.tf     variable.tf  (i did not seem to need to have an output to be used somewhere else.)
```

in iam_policy_document:

```
ls% main.tf     output.tf   variable.tf


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  statement {
     actions  = [
      "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:AddPermission",
      "SNS:RemovePermission",
      "SNS:DeleteTopic",
      "SNS:Subscribe",
      "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
      "SNS:Publish",
      "SNS:Receive"
    ]

    condition {
       test      = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceOwner"

      values = [
      var.account
      ]
    }

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
       type         = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    resources = [
      var.arn
    ]

    sid = "__default_statement_ID"
  }

  statement {
     actions  = [
      "sns:Publish"
    ]

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
       type         = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    resources = [
      var.arn
    ]

    sid = "TrustCWEToPublishEventsToMyTopic"
  }
}
```

in sns_topic_policy:

```
main.tf     output.tf   variable.tf

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "this" {
   arn = var.arn 
   policy = var.policy
}
```

I started redoing all of them in the order posted, than I would test as I go.  when all is said and done there is 4 items terraform needs to build; I know that for sure cause the non-module version is my base

So everything appears to work ok UNTIL I get to the aws_sns_topic_policy.

this is if I pound out sns_topic

```
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value:
```

I hit yes and it completes giving me the output I stated below.

now once I add the sns module, somewhere it goes haywire.

my outputs:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

caller_identity_out = 012345678910
cloudwatch_event_rule_out = Detect-Local-User-Creations
iam_policy_document_out = {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:Receive",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:AddPermission"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:012345678910:tf-SnsTopic-EmailSNSTopic-9JJZS66CE1CW",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "012345678910"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "TrustCWEToPublishEventsToMyTopic",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sns:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:012345678910:tf-SnsTopic-EmailSNSTopic-9JJZS66CE1CW",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

based off what I see, I have no clue what it is referring to. The only way I got this error to go away was with jsonencode. however, this is where the next error came about

```
iam_policy_document: Error: InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Policy Error: null status code: 400,
```

output.tf file

```
output "iam_policy_document_out" {
  value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json
}
```

It was mention jsonencode is not needed, if I take it out this is what happens.

Error received when I changed #policy = jsonencode("module.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out")

policy = "module.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out"

The ERROR::

```
dLocalUsers]
module.iam_policy_document.data.aws_iam_policy_document.this: Refreshing state...

Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'm' looking for beginning of value

  on ../../../modules/cloudwatch/sns_topic_policy/main.tf line 3, in resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "this":
   3:    policy = var.policy
```

the latest thing is when I implement the "alternatives" from the answer.
I get this error, but I do not see a problem. I cant understand what it is erroring. I have the output working, it is declared in sns_topic.. so either i am missing the obvious, I dont know...

```
Error: Reference to undeclared module

  on main.tf line 43, in module "sns_topic_policy":
  43:   policy = module.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out.json

No module call named "aws_iam_policy_document" is declared in the root module.
```

Comment: Its hard to speculate. What is `iam_policy_document_out`? Its form is not shown in your question.

Comment: aww yes, let me add some more information to the original question.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iam_policy_document_out` is already in `json` form:

```
value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json
```

Therefore, in the module, the following should be used:

```
module "sns_topic_policy" {
  source = "./sns_topic_policy/"
  arn    = module.SnsTopic.arn
  policy = module.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out
}
```

There still could be other issues, which are not apparent until you deploy the code.

### The alternative:

```
output "iam_policy_document_out" {
  value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this
}
```

```
module "sns_topic_policy" {
  source = "./sns_topic_policy/"
  arn    = module.SnsTopic.arn
  policy = module.aws_iam_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out.json
}
```

Comment: - that was initially what I put but I received this error. adding the jsonencode was the only way I could get it to get any further. I will add the error to the  bottom of the initial question.

Comment: @Randal the jsoneencode should not be required. This is how it is also done in [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic_policy), and I can confirm that it works in general. I will provide alternative way in the answer.

Comment: this is my lack of TF skills comes in. what I am doing is creating the variable in variable.tf, than actually putting the reference in the main.tf that I run.. It's probably totally wrong but that is all I could figure out.

Comment: @Randal Do you know where is this `invalid character 'm'` coming from? I don't see anything wrong with the policy.

Comment: when I change to your alternative, I get: a few undeclared errors. Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on main.tf line 65, in output "iam_policy_document_out":
  65:   value = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this

A data resource "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" has not been declared in the
root module.
rror: Reference to undeclared module

  on main.tf line 44, in module "sns_topic_policy":
  44:    policy = module.aws_policy_document.iam_policy_document_out.json

No module call named "aws_policy_document" is declared in the root module.

Comment: @Randal From what is posted, I can't see anything new what can be the problem. Maybe you can update your question with more details and the structure of your code. Where are the modules, what's inside them. p.s. output `iam_policy_document_out` should be in your modole, not parrent main.tf file.

Comment: ok I will try to pull it all together  and update my question...thx

Comment: so I was going over everything again. it appears your answer was the basic fix. I noticed I a reference to an output was wrong and that finally made the final piece complete. so this is done thanks for the info.

Comment: @Randal Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out and that my answer was helpful :-)